# In webkit browsers, sometimes part of the background appears white

Tags: css, webkit, rendering

I have this issue that appears only when using a webkit browser. Sometimes, when I reload my browser, certain parts of the background become white, and if I resize the window, it renders the background completely.

I was wondering, does anyone else have this issue? I don't think it's a markup issue, so I'm not going to attach any code. Just wondering if anyone has this issue, and if so, do you have any workarounds?

Picture of it happening: http://grab.by/5pys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty harmless, but it definitely is a frustrating issue. Not your fault though, sometimes when webkit renders the background, it just stops where the body element ends when the page loads from cache.

Perhaps try sending HTTP headers via PHP or other means by including this at the top of the page (before ANY output):

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: Aargh, that's what I was afraid of.

Are you aware of any work arounds?

Comment: best I could think is to have the page never load from cache by sending http headers. In PHP, I'd do this at the start of my page (before ANY output): (see code above... I edited it in.)

Comment: Hmm, okay, that wouldn't be too good for me, I need to spare server resources very carefully. Alright, thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you have any other solutions though, feel free to go for it :P